# Adding an Array property on the object at the given key

Tags: javascript

I need help in how to add an array property to an object with given key where the input is

```
var myObj = {};
var myArray = [1, 3];
```

and the output should be like this:

```
addArrayProperty(myObj, 'myProperty', myArray);

console.log(myObj.myProperty); // --> [1, 3]
```

I built a code and it gives me the exact output but when changing the values it gets undefined!

```js
  var myObj = {};
  var myArray = [1, 3];
  var myProperty = myArray;
function addArrayProperty(obj, key, arr) {
  myObj.myArray = myObj.myProperty;
  return myArray;
}
addArrayProperty(myObj, 'myProperty', myArray);
```

I believe that my code has something wrong can any one help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `myObj.myArray = myObj.myProperty;`

to `myObj.myProperty = myObj.myArray;`

```js
var myObj = {};
var myArray = [1, 3];
function addArrayProperty(obj, key, arr) {
  myObj[key] = arr;
  return myObj;
}
addArrayProperty(myObj, 'myProperty', myArray);

console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.myProperty); // [1, 3]
```

Comment: it still gives undefined when I console log myObj? do you know why?

Comment: @Salma It's works for me, try to run the code in my answer, If you still have a problem. Put your code on jsfiddle.net .